# How to match a date plus any time in a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, datetime, pattern-matching

I have looked at similiar questions and get this to work in strings, but cannot figure how to do the same on a json file.

I would like to count each activity type on each date in a json file. The below line works perfectly, however I do not know all the time values, therefore I would like to match *any* time on each date. I have tried using [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) but it does not return any values.

```
c = Counter(
    item['Activity'] for item in json_data
    if item['DateTime'] == '18/02/2019 09:14'
)
```

The code I am using to pattern match is below.

```
from collections import Counter
    import json
    import fnmatch
    import re

with open('dataset_3.json', 'r') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)  # loads json data
    c = Counter(
        item['Activity'] for item in json_data
        if item['DateTime'] == fnmatch.filter(item, '18/02/2019' + ' *')
    )
    print(c)
```

Comment: Im wondering if fnmatch can be used with dictionary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fnmatch` module is meant for matching filenames using UNIX-style globs. For general purpose pattern matching, [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) are usually a better bet.

However, since in this case you're simply matching the start of `item['DateTime']`, the [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method is the obvious choice:

```
c = Counter(
    item['Activity'] for item in json_data
    if item['DateTime'].startswith('18/02/2019 ')
)
```

Comment: ah ok I didn't realise fnmatch was just for mathing unix filenames. In that case regular expressions should have been what I looked at. That being said your solution actually works perfectly ! thank you !